# PrimeFaces Spinner with German locale

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In a Java web project we are using PrimeFaces 4.0 as a JSF extension. Now we ran into a problem with the Spinner (p:spinner) component in PrimeFaces. We embedded the spinner in our own custom tag to set some defaults such as the stepFactor and the locale. The body of the JSF tag looks like this:

```
    <p:spinner id="#{id}" value="#{value}" min="#{min}" max="#{max}" stepFactor="0.1" size="5" onchange="#{onchange}" >
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" locale="de_DE"/>
    </p:spinner>
```

This works fine as for the binding and the rendering of the component. In the following screenshot you see a float 2.6f that was set and properly formatted in the "de_DE" locale (with a comma instead of a dot as the decimal separator).

[image: Screenshot after rendering the page]

However, when the user uses the spinners buttons to change the value the formatting immediately gets wrong. The value is even parsed wrong from the component. In the next screenshot you can see the very same spinner once we clicked the "up" button once. Which should actually result in a value of "2,70" being displayed in the component.

[image: Screenshot after pressing the "up" butotn once.]

Has anybody else had similar problems like this before?

Is there a standard fix to the JavaScript handling the p:spinner component that we can apply here or do we really need to dig into PrimeFaces JS library and fix this on our own?

Comment: It looks like [there is movement](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/45a429a46280bf4a54af689b9c039063df1d334c) on this topic towards PF 7.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f:convertNumber` is a server-side conversion. The event of incrementing and decrementing the value is JavaScript, the `f:convertNumber` won't be taken into consideration until the value goes back to server, therefore an ugly JavaScript solution should be done.

I have created a patch for this problem and I used [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to convert the number into a localized version.

All you have to do is include [`pf.spinner.local.fix.js`](https://gist.github.com/hatemalimam/86ac51faa38569cad204) and set your preferred locale in the following way (in `document.ready`):

```
PF('spinnerWidgetVarName').cfg['local'] = 'de-DE';
```

There are a couple of notes to be taken:

- **Number.prototype.toLocaleString()**

[image]

- This patch is tested and confirmed on PrimeFaces 5.0 and 4.0

Here's a small example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/spinner/main.xhtml) and a [Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/spinner/main.xhtml)

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like exactly the thing I am looking for. Will try to upgrade to PrimeFaces 5.0 tomorrow and test this!

Comment: I checked this thing now. It behaves as expected and described. In our case also with PrimeFaces 4.0

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks it does not support prefix and suffix attributes.

Comment: Sadly the problem is unfixed even in PF 7.0.1 - and the fix on github does not work with ajax updated elements.

Comment: @cljk It looks like [there is movement](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/45a429a46280bf4a54af689b9c039063df1d334c) on this topic towards PF 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Primefaces Spinner does not support I18N.

A forum message asking to support locales has been posted since 2010 without any answer : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6398

A possible solution would be to use Primefaces' Extension component `timePicker` and customize it to manage your value.
See : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timePicker/basicUsage.jsf;jsessionid=7axadfz6by4g1787ncndsf12d
And : https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/PrimeFaces-Extensions-Locales

Or you could try to mess with JS...

Comment: It looks like [there is movement](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/45a429a46280bf4a54af689b9c039063df1d334c) on this topic towards PF 7.1.

Comment: Or I have long started to switch my actively maintained projects to ReactJS ;)